# Exporting data from Azure Cosmos DB (where type is MongoDB API)

Tags: database, azure, nosql, azure-cosmosdb

I need to export data from Azure Cosmos DB in CSV or JSON format to my local system.

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Export to where? Since you're using the MongoDB API, have you tried using the native MongoDB `mongoexport` tool? What specific issues are you having? Please edit to be more specific. Note: As written, it's also a bit too broad, since it's just a general requirement with little detail. And it also reads like a general documentation request.

Comment: hi, @DavidMakogon  I needed to export to my local system in JSON or CSV formate I just have no idea how can I do that because in Azure there is no way in the portal that I can export.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [cosmos db Migration Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data#MongoDB),please refer to this official article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-migrate

Or you could use Azure Data Factory for cosmos db mongo api to export data from cosmos db 
 into [azure blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage) `csv` file,please refer to this document:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-cosmos-db-mongodb-api

Comment: Import or export?

Comment: @jtlz2 Both of them.