# Azure CosmoDB Core (SQL) backup from external backup tool

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Does anyone know how can I extract DocumentDB data to an external backup tool? I mean using dumps, ad-hoc tools or API.

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to do that?

Comment: Look at the migration tool or Azure Data Factory: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59044209/exporting-a-database-or-container-from-azure-cosmos-db-to-my-local-storage

Comment: gaurav-mantri. I want to have a second data copy outside Azure to avoid a single provider. Seems no sense?

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069406/exporting-data-from-azure-cosmos-db-where-type-is-mongodb-api, it has couple useful links on how to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way for you to do this is to query your container to list all documents in your container and save them locally in json files. You could use any available Cosmos DB SDK to do so.

If you're looking for a tool to do that, may I request you to take a look at [`Cerebrata Cerulean`](https://www.cerebrata.com) (Disclosure: My company is behind this tool)? This tool has a feature to download documents from a container to the local computer. You can download all documents in a container or documents matching a query from a container using Cerulean.